# Interrupt a loop when a something arrives at the serial port

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I'll have a loop that keep refreshing a HTML file.When data arrives at the serial port that I'll choose through `serial` library. The data is coming from an Arduino board, and when the data arrives I'll read it and refresh some variables. I searched a little and see that Interrupts are usually used to that, but I'm thinking how to implement such interruption.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupts are usually used for very time critical things that can happen any time and which have therefor be executed with minimum delay.

I don't think what you want to do is a good use case for interrupts.

Why don't you try something like this: (pseudocode)

```
repeat forever:
  read serial port
  if data received:
    update variables (call a function that does that)
```

You can apply pretty much any example on processing serial commands out there. Just search the web.
It's always the same, read the serial input buffer frequently and check the received data. When the data is what you expect, do something. Then continue listening for further data.

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino core has a built-in pseudo-interrupt function, `serialEvent`, that kinda does what you want. It only checks in between each `loop()`:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent

But @Piglet's answer is probably the best solution—check if serial data is waiting for you, and if so, respond to it.

```
if (Serial.available()) {
    // do something
}
```